# retryWrites in mongodb python

Tags: python, nosql, pymongo, flask-pymongo

I use pymongo to implement mongo database.
I am trying to use the sessions and transactions for the management of operations, but I encountered this error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string.
```

I tried this solution but without result:

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/", retryWrites=False)
db = myclient["mydb"]
session = myclient.start_session()
```

Any help, thanks

Comment: Are you running your mongodb as a replicaset?

Comment: je suis entrain de le convertir de standalone à replicaset

Comment: Hmm not sure then. You need to be running a replicaset for transactions to work. Try moving the retryWrites to the connection string as suggested, e.g. `myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/&retryWrites=false")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run with the full connection string

```py
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/&retryWrites=false")
```

or specify all parameters

```py
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(
    host="localhost"
    port=27017
    retrywrites=False
)
```